# Are Resources freed when they have no observers?

Tags: resources, siesta-swift

Are Resources freed when they have no observers?
I have scenario where I want to cache some images but the view(s) displaying them may come and go. If I use RemoteImageView which handles its own observation of the image keyed on the URL but the users switches views back and forth causing the views to be reused then it loses track of the proper image.

Would it be reasonable to create a dedicated Service and EntityCache to insure the images aren't immediately flushed from the cache?

Any other suggestions would be appreciated.
Thx

Answer (score 0):

Resources live in memory until either (1) there is a low memory event or (2) you hit the service’s max cache size.

At that point, resource references become weak, which causes any not currently in use to be deallocated. If a resource has any observers, however, and if those observers’ owners have not been deallocated, then the service hangs on to the resource.

The [Memory Management section of the Siesta user guide](http://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/guide/memory/) discusses this extensively.